# How to display list items in Infopath

Tags: infopath

I want to display list items in InfoPath once i selected the particular column. Say I have selected Empid, automatically emp name, city, state and all the info related to emp id should display. Please give me a walkthrough so that i can understand since i am new to SP. I have created data connection but still not able to fetch the data. please guide me.

Comment: quick question, how many items are going to be in your list. Out of the box InfoPath does not play well with drop down items over a certain amount. Though there are alternative ways such as using a text field and submit button to return results. I dont have time to detail out right now, but should be able to get to it tonight. There should be a lot of blogs out there regarding this.

Comment: there around 2000 items in my list. it is "company active employee list". If i select emp id, should display all the info related the employee.

Comment: @Ramanjulu, Do you mean that the same employee can have many items with (or sets of)  "emp name, city, state and all the info related to emp id"? First, you tell about selecting particular columns (how is selection of columns related to particular delection of a empid?), then an item and in comment about "2000 items in my list"